# call a modal window from another file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component

How can I make a modal window call. From another file? I don't understand why I can't do it.

file 1:

```
<template>
    <section class="header">
      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header_start">
          <a href="#!" class="header__logo">YooMoney</a>
        </div>

        <div class="header-buttons_end">
          <button class="header_button" @click="isOpen = true; console.log('Button clicked')">Sign In</button>
          <teleport to="body">
            <Authorization  v-if="isOpen" />
          </teleport>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Authorization from "@/components/ModalWindow/Authorization.vue";
const isOpen = ref(false)
</script>
```

file 2:

```
<template>
  <MazDialog v-model="isOpen" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>
      Your content
    </p>
    <template #footer="{ close }">
      <MazBtn @click="close">
        Confirm
      </MazBtn>
    </template>
  </MazDialog>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import MazDialog from 'maz-ui/components/MazDialog'

  const isOpen = ref(false)
</script>
```

Uh, excuse me. I'm just learning.

I need when clicking on 'Sign in'. Open a modal window from the file.
I'm using nuxt.

Comment: what currently happens? Any errors in the browser *developer* console

Comment: Nothing happens and there are no errors (console).

Comment: Nothing in your code will change `isOpen` in "file 2" from false to true - so, of course it won't display

Comment: how can I make it work?

Comment: The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Is "file 1" the same as "MazDialog"? Then this needs to be stated. For direct parent-child relation you need to have show() and hide() methods in MazDialog and access its instance through template ref. Covered in the docs https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs

Answer (score 0):

You can call it by emit in your element by adding

@click="isOpen = true; newquery
like this

```
<button class="header_button" @click="newquery" >
```

```
const emit = defineEmits(['openmymodal'])
function newquery(new_value = true){
 emit ('openmymodal',new_value)
}
```

and in your other element you should add

```
<MazDialog v-model="isOpen" title="Dialog Title" @openmymodal="dothisfunction">


<script setup>

/// the rest of your code

const dothisfunction= (new_value) =>{
    isOpen.value = new_value
}
```